# authentication with join tables for multiple username or emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, devise

I need help on devise authentication (https://github.com/heartcombo/devise) about logins.

My db design has 3 tables that need 2 joins, so it can use any of a user's emails for login, using a single password.

```
profiles table
id
name

emails table
profile_id - foreign key from profiles table using has many
email

users table
profile_id - foreign key from profiles table using one-to-one relationship
encrypted_password
```

At the moment, I can only set 1 join in conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide any details except that 2 tables have a FK to a third. So I cannot provide much detail in response. But joining all 3 is a trivial exercise. it'll come in the format of:

```
 select 
   from profiles p
   join emails   e on e.profile_id = p.profile_id 
   join users    u on u.profile_id = p.profile_id
  where e.email = <email_address_parameter>
    and encryption_routine(<password_value_parameter>) = u.encrypted_password;
```

Comment: What is a "devise solution"?  Please provide details. It would help for you to review [ask].

Comment: currently, this is the code<br/>

```
user = Users.find_for_authentication( email: params[:email] )
if user
  if Users.valid_password?(params[:password])
    # login success
  else
    # incorrect password
else
  # email do not exist
end
```

this will join another table but its useless coz i need 2 straight joins.. users -> profiles -> emails

```
user = Users.find_for_authentication( email: params[:email] )

# change to

user = Users.find_for_authentication( email: params[:email], :join => :profiles )
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have the correct model relations.

```
if(email = Email.find_by(email: params[:email])).present?
  if(email.profile.users.where(encrypted_password: encrypt(params[:password])).count > 0)
    # login success
  else
    # wrong password
  end 
else
  # email not exists
end
```

Comment: is there a way using devise?